# How to fix error problem when i import excel to postgresql?

Tags: sql, excel, postgresql, cjk

I am trying to import an excel file with some Japanese data in it. I tried solutions that use COPY, use pgadmin import but I always end with an error message:

> C:/Users/設備53/Desktop/Book4.csv : Invalid argument

and for the way using copy:

> ERROR: could not open file "C:\Users\設備53\Desktop\Book4.csv" for reading:
>   No such file or directory
>   SQL state: 58P01

I I tried many little things e.g. be careful of the encoding, changing the security parameter etc that I saw on the net.